# HashiCorp Vault multiple values for ldap.urls (list of urls)

Tags: spring-boot, ldap, hashicorp-vault, spring-ldap, spring-vault

I have configuration for spring ldap in application.yml as:

```
ldap:
  urls:
    - ldaps://host01.acme.com:636
    - ldaps://host02.acme.com:636
    - ldaps://host03.acme.com:636
    - ldaps://host04.acme.com:636
```

I would like to place it in HashiCorp Vault, but when I add next ldap.urls key, it overwrites previous one (actually it's key).

How can I add into HashiCorp Vault a list of urls as value under ldap.urls?

Answer (score 0):

I looks, that

```
ldap.urls.0=ldaps://host01.acme.com:636
ldap.urls.1=ldaps://host02.acme.com:636
ldap.urls.2=ldaps://host03.acme.com:636
ldap.urls.3=ldaps://host04.acme.com:636
```

works.